# NSString key for value

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

```
NSString *userUpdate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"grant_type=password&Password=%@&UserName=%@&SchoolId=1",[params valueForKey:@"UserName"@"Password"]];
```

When I am running this code I am getting an error. Is this code correct?

Comment: please edit the question and apply necessary formatting to make it  more sensible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `NSDictionary` Get only one value using `valueForKey`.
For Getting Password access like `[params valueForKey:@"Password"]`

For UserName use syntax like `[params valueForKey:@"UserName"]`

Can't get both value same time use like `[params valueForKey:@"UserName"@"Password"]`

Below is sample code:

```
NSString *userUpdate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"grant_type=password&Password=%@&UserName=%@&SchoolId=1",[params valueForKey:@"Password"],[params valueForKey:@"UserName"]];
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem in your code is you have written %@ twice and supplied only single value, that is the main reason behind error.

In `NSDictionary` you can get only one value at a the time using `valueForKey`.

Use this code

```
NSString *userUpdate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"grant_type=password&Password=%@&UserName=%@&SchoolId=1",[params valueForKey:@"Password"],[params valueForKey:@"UserName"]];
```

Comment: can you add more description to your answer so that OP gets clear idea what he is doing wrong